# Django: pycharm: unversioned files

Tags: python, django, pycharm

When I did 'makemigrations' on 'django', the generated file became 'unversioned files'.

I don't know why.

How can I change this unversioned one to versioned files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your `unversioned files` in your `git` branch.
$ git add `unversioned files name`

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm, right-click the file and select "Git | Add" from the context menu, or drag & drop it from the unversioned files node to a changelist.